# Can I remove and replace barbed connector in 1/2" drip tube?

Tags: irrigation

I have a drip irrigation system with 1/4" tubes connected to the 1/2" main tube via punched-in barbed connectors.  I'm now making some adjustments.

Is it possible to remove and replace these barbed connectors, or will that damage the 1/2" tube?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the small tube goes into the main pipe with a straight barbed connector - yes, I have removed and reinserted several times. Eventually you may need a plug if the hole gets larger after many unpluggings.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

If the tube is old and brittle than you may crack it. 
If you do crack the tube, or you have to cut it, you can buy new inexpensive tubing  and barbed couplers as well.

Heat it up with a hair dryer or hot water and slowly wiggle it back and forth as you pull. Some come apart more easily then others.